# UIPageViewController Inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a custom table view cell that has nothing except an image view. I also have an array of images  and I want to be able to page through the images in the cell. Is using a page view controller the way to go or should I go about it another way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a page view controller. However, an easier approach would be to use a collection view controller. The cell in the collection view could be of the same size as the table view cell.